# Why do particles in a medium have different speeds?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

If thermal conduction occurs because of particles colliding with each other and imparting kinetic energy to each other, won’t the particles of an isolated medium collide with each other until the kinetic energies of every particle become equal? Why is there an uneven distribution of particle speeds?

Comment: The particles will have different speeds for a while, but it becomes the same after a while...?? Reality needs more complex analysis with QM, etc.

Comment: @stygian this is indeed the case for an ideal gas model, which reproduces many properties of real gases. A different model for free particles which takes into account the presence of an external field is the Boltzmann distribution, which yields a difference in particles speed due to the effect of this field. It can reproduce features of the atmosphere and others. But here you see why unevenness arises. Can you point out a distribution for which you can't find the origin of unevenness?

Comment: Statistical mechanics can answer this. The maxwell Boltzmann distribution of velocities of an ideal gas describes a system that has come into equilibrium with it's degrees of freedom. Moreover the particles are distributed ergodically in phase space and thus represent the lowest  energy/maximum entropy configuration of these particles. My hunch is that a uniform distribution of velocities could indeed have the same total energy but will also have lower entropy and is thus an unstable configuration. As for a more mechanical description I need to think harder! Great question a big +1 from me.

Comment: I think he's asking for an intuitive explanation of why stable energy distributions can be "distributed" over a range at all.

Comment: Why is this being VTC'd as *unclear*. The question asks why the velocity distribution has a non-zero width. What's unclear about that?

Answer (score 1):

For 1 dimensional case you are right, but in 2+ dimensional case "side collisions" occurs which may produce particles with speeds different from average. Imagine one particle moves to the right and another pushes it from the bottom giving away all it's impulse.